# Is there a way to modify an exception while keeping the existing call stack in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, exception

I have a job that is throwing an exception and I'd like to have the calling process report the exception call stack in a debug log while presenting a useful error to the user.

Contents of test.ps1:

```
Function foo {
    throw "bar" 
}

Try {
    foo
} catch {
    throw
}
```

Calling code:

```
Start-job test -filepath test.ps1
Receive-job test
$error[0] | select *
```

I'd like the output to indicate that the error occurred in test.ps1, but it just says that it occurred in the scriptblock in the exception output for the call stack.

I could see this in 2 ways:
1) updating the call stack shown to indicate the script name instead of just scriptblock, or
2) updating the exception message to have the script name in the exception message while keeping the existing call stack in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

it is not an exact answer, I know. 
Here are some throws that helped me a lot so far. See if you can use them:

```
$PSItem.InvocationInfo
```

contains additional information collected by PowerShell about the function or script where the exception was thrown. EG:

```
$PSItem.InvocationInfo | Format-List *
```

Others:

```
$PSItem.Exception.StackTrace
$PSItem.Exception.Message
$PSItem.Exception.InnerException
```

update: to throw a custom message i did:

```
catch {
 $message = "Something bad happened in the inner script. See stack: $PSItem.Exception.InnerException"
throw $message
}
```

Comment: Hmm but these are all readonly properties. I know they exist but not how I'd modify them in the way I need.

Comment: sorry it is not what you were looking for. I am at beginner level with powershell  :(. I added in the comment how to throw a custom error. Maybe it helps